# PHP: Split string that needed

Tags: php, split

based on my question above, below is

```
$staff1 = "Peter Sondak (Top Pop - F09)";
$staff2 = "James Rodri (Top Pop - F12)";
$staff3 = "Allan Kang (Top Pop - F31)";

echo $staff1;
echo "<br>";
echo $staff2;
echo "<br>";
echo $staff3;
```

and the result will like this

> Peter Sondak (Top Glove - F09)
>
> James Rodri (Top Glove - F12)
>
> Allan Kang (Top Glove - F31)

FYI, F09, F12, and F31 represent the factory. Now, I want to split it by only display the factory, for example, F09, without includes the name.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: why dont you use [an array](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/20f1427eb56896de9fda881aca8e7c8c5e495d06)? considering your code is hardcoded

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `regular expression` to parse the `substring` between the two characters:

```
$staffList = [ "Peter Sondak (Top Pop - F09)", "James Rodri (Top Pop - F12)", "Allan Kang (Top Pop - F31)" ];
function getFactory($staff){
     preg_match_all('/-(.*)\)/', $staff, $matches);
     return trim($matches[1][0]);
}
for($i = 0; $i < count($staffList); $i++)
     echo getFactory($staffList[$i]) . "<br>";
```

Output:

```
F09
F12
F31
```

Comment: When the data is in loop, I got this error,  Cannot redeclare getFactory() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\ldap\index2.php:119)

Comment: You should declare the function once. I updated the answer to use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to search within your strings.

```
$staff = "Peter Sondak (Top Pop - F09)";
preg_match("/\((.*?)\)/", $staff, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

you can use online tools like [regexr](https://regexr.com/) to play around with your regular expressions and tweak them (there are many websites like this, this is just an example)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function get_factory($full)
{
  preg_match_all("/\\((.*?)\\)/", $full, $factory);
  $factory = $factory[1][0];
  $factory = substr($factory, strpos($factory, " - F") + 4);
  $factory = "F".$factory;
  return $factory;
}
?>
<?php
    $staff1 = "Peter Sondak (Top Pop - F09)";
    $staff2 = "James Rodri (Top Pop - F12)";
    $staff3 = "Allan Kang (Top Pop - F31)";

    echo get_factory($staff1);
    echo "<br>";
    echo get_factory($staff2);
    echo "<br>";
    echo get_factory($staff3);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you.

```
 function factory($staff) {
 $a = preg_match("/(?<=\-\s).+(?=\))/",$staff,$arr);
 return $arr[0];
 }
 
$staff1 = "Peter Sondak (Top Pop - F09)";
echo factory($staff1);
```

OR

```
 function factory(...$staff) {
 $arr = [];  
 foreach($staff as $staf) {
 $a = preg_match("/(?<=\-\s).+(?=\))/",$staf,$array);
 $arr[] = $array[0];     
 }   
 return $arr;
 }
 
    $staff1 = "Peter Sondak (Top Pop - F09)";
    $staff2 = "James Rodri (Top Pop - F12)";
    $staff3 = "Allan Kang (Top Pop - F31)";
    print_r(factory($staff1,$staff2,$staff3));
```